# Build expression tree from nested list

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have bunch of classes that have nested lists. For example: Class Gpoint has List of Points, Point has list of Positions, Position has list of Details, Detail has list of Codes. Point also has list of Features, Feature has list of properties and so on...
I am trying to filter those classes based on different properties from different objects from lists that are on different nest level. I know how to do it by using LINQ queries but I need another solution.
I've been reading about Expressions and I concluded that my goal has to be reachable by using them. I've been experimenting little bit but I got stuck at the beginning because I cannot figure out how to write this simple query by using expressions. I'm using VB.NET and .NET Framework 3.5

```
    If PropCriterias.Count > 0 Then
        qPP = (From pt In qPP
               From feat In pt.Feature.Features
               From prop In feat.Properties
               Where  prop.IsDefined = True)
               Select pt).ToList
    End If
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly if I say that: "You're trying to filter out different objects and save them in a collection from a larger collection."? Or what is the point of finding all the items from qPP.Feature.Features.Properties.Where(x => x.IsDefined == true).ToList(); ? PS sorry for the C#. DS

Comment: Actually, this is only part of complex query. From this list I need to return pt and filtered list of it's feats and filtered list of its props. But I need to understand how to write this part of code to apply that in other situation.